# Html in php causing page not to load

Tags: php, html

I am working on a website and I have a navigation bar at the top I am making it so if the user is logged in it shows their username in a dropdown and if they aren't logged in it shows a sign-up button...

But my problem is when i try loading my webpage chrome gives "This page isn't working"

This is my code:

```
<div class="navbar">
    <a href="#home" class="left">Home</a>
    <?php
    if (LoginManager::isLoggedIn ()) {
        echo '<a href="#login" class="right">
        <div class="dropdown" style="float: right;">
        <button class="dropbtn">'.$user.'</button>
        <div class="dropdown-content">
        <a href="my-account.php">Settings</a>
        <a href="logout.php">Logout</a>
        </div>
        </div>
        </a>';
    }else{
        echo '<a href="#" onclick="document.getElementById("id01").style.display=\'block\'" class="right">Sign in / Sign up</a>';
    }
    ?>
</div>
```

Comment: you might need to escape the quotes in the onclick... onclick="document.getElementById(\"id01\")....

Comment: ini_set('display_errors',1); on debug mode and try to know the error

Comment: change your else part to:` echo '<a href="#" onclick="document.getElementById(\'id01\').style.display=\'block\'" class="right">Sign in / Sign up</a>';`. Also make sure `LoginManager::isLoggedIn ()` doesnt throw any error

Comment: Use this `onclick="document.getElementById('id01').style.display=\'block\'"`

Comment: @gavgrif 's suggestion fixed it i needed to escape the onclick, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the comments given, you did not escape the quotes on this line;

```
echo '<a href="#" onclick="document.getElementById("id01").style.display=\'block\'" class="right">Sign in / Sign up</a>';
```

Change it to this,

```
echo '<a href="#" onclick="document.getElementById(\"id01\").style.display=\'block\'" class="right">Sign in / Sign up</a>';
```

Or use single quotes,

```
echo '<a href="#" onclick="document.getElementById('id01').style.display=\'block\'" class="right">Sign in / Sign up</a>';
```